# How do you store the results of some python code for use in another calculation?

Tags: python, time-series, moving-average, algorithmic-trading, binance

I am a day trader who is new to python and learning every day. I have written a basic script or maybe you call it a function? but some basic python code that pulls the best bid/offer data from an API for me on repeat every 5 seconds

I now want a rolling average of the data coming in the from the API every 5 seconds so i can compare the current data against the rolling average

My problem is I have no idea where to start or what I should be looking to learn. Any help would be great! Even just to point me in the right direction.

Does the data need to be stored into a .csv that is updated each 5 seconds? or can all this be done within the code?

Thanks in advance for any help, code is below

```
import time
from binance.client import Client

api_key = "###"
api_secret = "###"

while True:
 client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

 ticker_info = (client.get_ticker(symbol="ETHUSDT"))

 bid_qty = int(float(ticker_info['bidQty']))
 ask_qty = int(float(ticker_info['askQty']))
 bbo_delta = ask_qty-bid_qty
 print("Ask=")
 print(ask_qty)
 print("Bid=")
 print(bid_qty)
 print("Delta=")
 print(bbo_delta)
 print("-")
 time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this types of quires may have various possibilities. As per your explanation, I got to know that, You want to fetch the data that get generated every five second.

So, you can **scrape** the data via beautiful soup if you are using python.

As the data is updated in every five second, after some times, it may be huge too . So, in that case properly stored data maybe in a csv or in a excel or in a database , It would be great help for you too.

Just **scrape** the data and store the data in a csv format or if you are using API, store that in a proper dataframe.

My suggestion would be use Beautiful Soup (BS4) and read some documentation and just in a few lines of code, store the data in a csv.

Documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice, 

The data is actually already being "scraped" in a sense as its coming in live from the API each second so need need for beautiful soup.

The issue is that I cant calculate a rolling average within the code as the data is not stored anywhere. so my question is can I store the data in the code somehow instead of a csv?...  maybe its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

By a 'rolling average' do you mean over minutes, hours or days? You can get a one minute rolling mean by putting the values into a list of len <= 12 and dropping the 'old' (only one minute old) values as new ones arrive. List is going to get really big as the roll time window gets big enough to be useful (len=120k for a one week average). Hard to imagine volatility that would make a 5 sec sampling interval valuable, but I know nothing about day trading. If you do want that short an interval and a 100k size data set, reading and writing to a file is going to be too slow.

Try writing code for a one hour rolling average with samples every minute. That will get you started. You can then post the code with specific questions and incrementally work to your goal.

Comment: Google stacks and queues to see how to append() into your list and pop() out of it.

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks so much Colin, I’m going to Google some things you said and do some experimenting then I’ll come back here with the code I come up with as you said. Thanks very much for your time! I appreciate the help.

Comment: Happy to help. You might also write a little function to emulate client.get_ticker() to help you experiment and debug. You can use random() to return plausible debugging values.